# Insert group only if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, sql, forms

I am a little stuck with this. I am trying to insert groups of items only if that groups checkbox is clicked.  I have tested the SQL insert without the checkboxes, and the SQL works perfectly and inserts the data. But when I added the checkboxes and if/else statement, it started to give me troubles.

For example:
-If I select group 1 and not group 2 - the SQL works correctly only inserting group 1 data
-If I select group 2 and not group 1 - The insert still inserts group 1 data
-If I select group 1 and group 2 - The SQL inserts two rows of group 1 data
-If I do not select any groups, then I get "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home..." - which I will sort out later.

I have marked "Group 1" and "Group 2". I need the code to insert only the groups if checkbox is clicked, and ignore the non clicked checkbox groups. Any help would be great. Thanks.

I have been testing with the following code:

**Form:**

```
<form id="Form" method="post" action="/random.php" name="Form">
<input id="itemCurrency" type="hidden" value="2" name="itemCurrency"></input>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="itemHolder">
<img class="itemImg thumbnail" src="http://images.com/i/images.jpg"></img>
<div class="itemName">swim Shorts Wi...</div><
<div class="itemPrice">$33.33</div>
<div class="itemHref"><a target="_blank" href="http://random.com/product.aspx?id=40"> Visit Item Page </a></div>
</div>
</div>
   //GROUP 1    
     <input id="itemCheckBox[]" type="checkbox" value="checked" name="itemCheckBox[]"></input>
     <input id="itemName[]" type="hidden" value="some random text" name="itemName[]"></input>
     <input id="itemHref[]" type="hidden" value="http://random.com/product.aspx?id=2140" name="itemHref[]"></input>
     <input id="itemImg[]" type="hidden" value="http://images.com/i/image1s.jpg" name="itemImg[]"></input>
     <input id="itemPrice[]" type="hidden" value="$37.33" name="itemPrice[]"></input>
   //END GROUP 1    

<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="itemHolder">
<img class="itemImg thumbnail" src="http://images.com/i/image_xl.jpg"></img>
<div class="itemName">Bomber Jacket With Fur</div>
<div class="itemPrice"> $88.88</div>
<div class="itemHref"><a target="_blank" href="http://random.com/Bomber-Jacket-With-fur/..">Visit Item Page</a></div>

</div>
</div>
   //GROUP 2
     <input id="itemCheckBox[]" type="checkbox" value="checked" name="itemCheckBox[]"></input>
     <input id="itemName[]" type="hidden" value="Bomber Jacket With Fur" name="itemName[]"></input>
     <input id="itemHref[]" type="hidden" value="http://random.com/Bomber-Jacket-With-fur/.." name="itemHref[]"></input>
     <input id="itemImg[]" type="hidden" value="http://images.com/i/image_xl.jpg" name="itemImg[]"></input>
     <input id="itemPrice[]" type="hidden" value="$88.88" name="itemPrice[]"></input>
   //END GROUP 2


     <input id="site" type="hidden" value="1" name="site"></input>
     <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="yes" name="submit_form"></input>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if($submitForm == "yes" && $site == "1") {

foreach($_POST['itemCheckBox'] as $key => $val)
          {
   $fields[] = array(
      'itemCheckBox'=>$_POST['itemCheckBox'] [$key],
      'itemName' =>$_POST['itemName'] [$key],
      'itemHref' =>$_POST['itemHref'] [$key],
      'itemImg' =>$_POST['itemImg'] [$key],
      'itemPrice' =>$_POST['itemPrice'][$key] );

      //Remove non numaric characters from price(leave commas).
      $itemPrice = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/s', '', $itemPrice);

    //Data fields not in form
       $userId = "username";
       $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
       $itemType = "ADD LATER";
       $itemOutFit = "ADD LATER";
       $site = "1";
       $itemSale = "1";

      //Only insert if checkbox is clicked --NOT WORKING, ????
     if (isset($_POST['itemCheckBox'])){
            echo "CHECKED";
            echo "<br>";
    /*** INSERT data ***/
     $sql = "INSERT INTO items (userId,itemHref,itemImg,itemPrice,itemName,userIp,itemSite,itemType,itemCurrency,itemOutFit,itemSale) VALUES (:userId,:itemHref,:itemImg,:itemPrice,:itemName,:userIp,:itemSite,:itemType,:itemCurrency,:itemOutFit,:itemSale)";
      $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array(':userId'=>$userId, 
                ':itemHref'=>$itemHref[$key], 
                ':itemImg'=>$itemImg[$key], 
                ':itemPrice'=>$itemPrice[$key], 
                ':itemName'=>$itemName[$key], 
                ':userIp'=>$userIp, 
                ':itemSite'=>$itemSite, 
                ':itemType'=>$itemType,
                ':itemCurrency'=>$itemCurrency,
                ':itemOutFit'=>$itemOutFit,
                ':itemSale'=>$itemSale));   

                               } else  {
                               echo "NOT CHECKED";
                               echo "<br>";

                               }

/*  
echo $conn->errorCode();
echo "<br>"; ('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')
echo $conn->errorInfo();
echo "<br>";
//die(print_r($q->errorInfo(), true));
 */                
                         }
```

**UPDATE** Tried to strip php down to basic code, still no luck. Does the same thing....anyone have an idea how I can fix this.

```
            foreach($_POST['itemCheckBox'] as $key => $val)
                       {
                       $i = 0;
            $itemCheckBox = $_POST['itemCheckBox'];
            $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
            $itemHref = $_POST['itemHref'];
            $itemImg = $_POST['itemImg'];
            $itemPrice = $_POST['itemPrice'];

  echo $i;
  echo "<br>";     
  $i = $i +1;

                     if (isset($_POST['itemCheckBox'])){
                                                 echo "<br>";
                                                         echo "CHECKED";
                                                         echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo $itemCheckBox[$i];     
                echo "<br>";
        echo $itemName[$i];    
            echo "<br>";
        echo $itemHref[$i];  
            echo "<br>";
        echo $itemImg[$i];  
            echo "<br>";
                echo $itemPrice[$i];   

                         } else  {
                       echo "NOT CHECKED";
                       echo "<br>";
                       $i = $i +1;

                       }

               }
```

Comment: Try to output `$_POST` data in all cases and see what you have. THe problem is that if you don't select any checkboxes, or select only 1 - other data (`itemName, itemHref`) will still be posted as array and will have 2 elements each.

Comment: Is the $fields array being used in the code? I see a lot of variables like $itemPrice and $itemImg, should those be $fields[$key]['itemPrice'] and $fields[$key]['itemImg']?

Comment: LEVI- I have changed the variable names like you said, but it still does the same thing when I try to insert.

Comment: If you print_r($fields[$key]); before you execute the query, does it show the right data, or is that incorrect as well? (after the line that says $q = $conn->prepare($sql);)

Comment: @u_mulder - I was thinking that was the problem, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. Pullin my hair out here. Spent the last few hours trying all kinds of things...but no luck.

Comment: @levi - Thanks for the advice. I changed the code but still no dice :( any other suggestions??

Comment: Did you try the print_r($fields[$key]) I mentioned a couple comments up? Did that come back right or wrong?

Comment: @Levi - I tried it......if i only select "group 2" it gives me the array data for "group 1", if i select both "group 1+2" it gives the correct array data. I only select "group 1" it gives the correct array data.

Comment: I just added an edit to my answer to help fix the edited code you posted. The $i=0 at the top of your foreach loop was keeping it on the first item because it kept getting reset to 0 each time it started the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things I spots that may be contributing to the issue:

1. In your PHP you have a line that has this:

   ```
   //Remove non numaric characters from price(leave commas).
   $itemPrice = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/s', '', $itemPrice);
   ```

   I don't see where $itemPrice is defined though, should it be:

   ```
   $itemPrice = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/s', '', $fields['itemPrice']);
   ```
2. Your issue of getting the "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home..." can be solved by checking to make sure it exists and is an array beforelooping. You can use !empty() and is_array() to check.

   if(!empty($_POST['itemCheckBox']) and is_array($_POST['itemCheckBox'])){}

**Side Issue:**
Your IDs for the inputs are all the same, "itemCheckBox[]", "itemName[]", etc.. are the same ID used for all of them. This may cause problems in the future if you want to use javascript or css properly.

**Edit:**
In your revised example the issue is that each time it cycles into the loop it is setting $i=0 because you declare it at the top of the foreach. If you go back to using the $key as the index it should work. See below:

```
//GROUP 1 checkbox
     <input id="itemCheckBox[]" type="checkbox" value="0" name="itemCheckBox[]"></input>

//GROUP 2 checkbox
     <input id="itemCheckBox[]" type="checkbox" value="1" name="itemCheckBox[]"></input>
```

I may also advise that you adjust your HTML items to match the Key you are passing:

```
<input id="itemName[1]" type="hidden" value="Bomber Jacket With Fur" name="itemName[]"></input>
     <input id="itemHref[1]" type="hidden" value="http://random.com/Bomber-Jacket-With-fur/.." name="itemHref[]"></input>
     <input id="itemImg[1]" type="hidden" value="http://images.com/i/image_xl.jpg" name="itemImg[]"></input>
     <input id="itemPrice[1]" type="hidden" value="$88.88" name="itemPrice[]"></input>
```

```
foreach($_POST['itemCheckBox'] as $key => $val) {
  $itemCheckBox = $_POST['itemCheckBox'];
  $itemName = $_POST['itemName'];
  $itemHref = $_POST['itemHref'];
  $itemImg = $_POST['itemImg'];
  $itemPrice = $_POST['itemPrice'];


  if (isset($_POST['itemCheckBox'])){
      echo "<br>";
      echo "CHECKED";
      echo $itemCheckBox[$key];
      echo "<br>";
      echo "<br>";
      echo $itemCheckBox[$itemCheckBox[$key]];     
      echo "<br>";
      echo $itemName[$itemCheckBox[$key]];    
      echo "<br>";
      echo $itemHref[$itemCheckBox[$key]];  
      echo "<br>";
      echo $itemImg[$itemCheckBox[$key]];  
      echo "<br>";
      echo $itemPrice[$itemCheckBox[$key]];   

    } else  {
      echo "NOT CHECKED";
      echo "<br>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for input, I have made the changes you suggested. I only left the id's the same for the "testing" period. After I have all the PHP working smoothly I was planning to make a few changes like that :)

Comment: Thanks for the help...I tried that code, but it still does not give the correct info. if I select only "group 2", For some reason it still gives "group 1" data. Almost like the array [$key] only increases by 1 if itemCheckBox is set. I tried to add $key++ to the else part to fix this, but it did not work....

Comment: Ah, can't believe I overlooked that. Since all of info for the items are in hidden inputs, all of that gets passed in. So when only 1 checkbox gets checked, it will pull from the first item. When both get in there are enough "keys" to pull from both. Is it feasible for you to add keys to the items? I modified my answer above with an example of that. This would better bind your checkboxes to the item info.

Comment: Done, it worked perfectly...thank you for your patience and help. Just in the knick of time too, any longer and I would not have had any hair left lol.....  +10 karma for you ;)